# Can we include "strcmp" in printf statement?

Tags: c

Can anyone explain what is the meaning of this line of code

```
      printf("%d",strcmp("strcmp()","strcmp()"))
```

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: Did you compile and run this code and see the output it prints? Here is `strcmp` description https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm

Comment: What is being compared in that ?

Comment: Attempt to split it up into multiple statements (with the help of temporary variables), and see if you can understand it better then.

Comment: It might be clearer with the similar code `printf("%d", strcmp("apples", "pears"));` as the original literal text was perhaps intended to confuse - not being executable code.

Comment: @Weather  , thanks man

Comment: It has no meaning on SO.  It is of no use to future users/visitors.

Answer (score 1):

The code is just a joke...

It just compares two fixed strings. To make it confusing the two strings contain the name of a library function (strcmp) but that - of cause - doesn't make it a function call.

The code

```
printf("%d",strcmp("strcmp()","strcmp()"))
```

is similar to

```
printf("%d",strcmp("A","A"))
```

It will print `0` (zero) as the strings are identical and `strcmp` return zero when strings have an exact compare.

Answer (score 0):

strcmp() is responsible for lexicographic comparison of strings(character order).i.e.first character compared with first character if equal then second and so on.
Its signature is as follows:

```
int strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)
```

http://forgetcode.com/C/1026-strcmp-lexicographically-compares-two-strings
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm

This function return values that are as follows:

if Return value < 0 then it indicates str1 is less than str2.

if Return value > 0 then it indicates str2 is less than str1.

if Return value = 0 then it indicates str1 is equal to str2.